# Jquery post is being called when I do not want to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Good morning people!

I have the following problem: I send the data of a form by , but before the form I have a .post in jquery.
When I click to send the form from the jquery part it goes right, however, when I click to send the form,
It sends first by the jquery and then sends by the form, and that gives error.

I'll post the code, I really appreciate the help!

Entrada.jsp

```
<td><a href="entradaMateriais2" class="btn btn-xs btn-info entradaMateriais"
                                    data-toggle="modal" name="codigoTeste" 
                                  data-id="${list.id_material }" >Entrada</a> </td>
    //Here begins the modal                     


    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="#entradaMateriais2"
                data-toggle="modal"> Entrada de Materiais </a>
    <div id="entradaMateriais2" class="modal fade"
                aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog"
                tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 550px;">

    //...... Omitted code to not get too big

    <form action="cadEntradaEstq.html" method="post">

    //...... Omitted code to not get too big

    </form>                     

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Entrada de Material</button>
```

Jquery code

```
$(".entradaMateriais").on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id'); $("#fid").val(id);

        var nome =      $('#nome' + id).text();     $("#fnome").val(nome);
        var codigo =    $('#codigo' + id).text();       $("#fcodigo").val(codigo);
        var categoria = $('#categoria' + id).text();   $("#fcategoria").val(categoria);
        $.post("../ControleMovEstoque", {codigoTeste : codigo}, function(data){

            var dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);

            var local = JSON.stringify(dataJSON[0].local).replace(/\"/g, ""); 
                $("#local").text(local).val(local);   

            var qtdEstoque = JSON.stringify(dataJSON[0].qtdEstoque).replace(/\"/g, ""); 
                $("#qtdEstoque").val(qtdEstoque);
            var qtdMin = JSON.stringify(dataJSON[0].qtdMin).replace(/\"/g, ""); 
                $("#qtdMin").val(qtdMin); 
            var qtdMax = JSON.stringify(dataJSON[0].qtdMax).replace(/\"/g, ""); 
                $("#qtdMax").val(qtdMax); 

        }); 

        $("#entradaMateriais2").modal();
        });
```

That is:

If I click the button below, everything goes well:

[image]

And open this new window ... if I click on register, it goes through the code of the button "Entrada" again

[image]

Comment: Because of the fact that you omitted a part of your HTML, I have to ask: Do you have one form inside of another, because that will cause problems as it is impossible.

Comment: You can prevent default action of button/form submission

Comment: why is it like 
`<form>`

`<form>`

`<button type='submit'>`
Either the second form tag is a closing one, or, it's another form inside the first form, for which you can call `preventDefault()`

Comment: use <a> tag in place of <button> or add onclick="return false;" attribute to the <button> tag.

Comment: It is not a form inside another form. What happens is that I have a jquery that takes the class "entradaMateriais" and makes a post (element name = "codigoTeste").

Further down, I have the <form action = "cadEntradaEstq.html" method = "post">. However, when I click the submit post, it calls the jQuery "entradaMateriais" first

Comment: I made an edit, because I forgot about a / in <form>